# How Magento(Community Edidtion) checks if customer/user is logged in?

Tags: magento2, magento-community

This problem is more theoretical than practical. Im writing cms security work for my studies. I managed to find how Magento deals with XSS, CSRF, SQL injection, etc. But I cant find how and where Magento checks if admin user and customer is logged in, how Magento controls access to its parts.

Can someone, please, explain where in the code Magento Community Edition checks if user is logged in or if session exists? And give some examples or at least files or directories where to look in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magento2 frontend check is simillarly provided by `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` class and its `isLoggedIn()` method. This method checks if the model has customer id value set and if so if this customer id exists in the database. The third check (`!$this->getIsCustomerEmulated()`) is related to persistent module which saves cart and customer data in session after logging out.

Now how this class get customer id? This is done during logging. In `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost::execute()` method. There username and password from `POST` request are taken and passed to `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::authenticate()` method. This method fetches customer from database by username, do password validation and if everything is successful returns customer data object. Which in turn is passed to  `setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn()` method in session model class.

The important thing to note here is that session object extends not `Magento\Framework\DataObject` as many classes but `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager`. This parent class defines its own `__call` magic method and passes all `get...` and `set...` calls to `Magento\Framework\Session\Storage` class which saves and reads everything from `$_SESSION`. So each call `setCustomerId($id)` on session class will in fact save that data in `$_SESSION`. Additionaly `SessionManager` class initialize the session in its constructor to read previously saved data from php session array.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin, the authentication check is made in the admin action controller (`Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`) within the `preDispatch()` method. All admin pages are (or should be) served from an action controller that extends this class. Within the `preDispatch()` method, a check is made to the admin session model (`Mage_Admin_Model_Session`) to see if the user is logged in. It's that session model that keeps track of user's authentication status from page-to-page.

On the frontend, the class `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` holds the user's authentication status. When login information is submitted, `Mage_Customer_Model_Session->login()` is called with the username and password, and that call returns true if the data authenticates. After being authenticated, `Mage_Customer_Model_Session->isLoggedIn()` returns true while the session is valid.